# A Riley Riddle For All

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

Here is another Riley riddle. Hope you all enjoy!

> Prefix of the word is a commonplace, where ales and good times set the pace.
>
> On to the infix, you and I can all do, think of eating ice cream without a spoon.
>
> Suffix is next, the dimensions of all, contemplating how big or how small?
>
> The title of this riley may also relate, as may the side of the riddle this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> Publicize

Prefix:

> PUB

Infix:

> LIC  (lick)

Suffix:

> CIZE  (size)

Hint:

> When you publicize something, you POST it FOR ALL to see

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> PUBLICITY?

Prefix:

> PUB

Infix:

> LIC - you lick ice cream

Suffix:

> CITY - because idk

Additional:

> Title is a clue - public means accessible by all.

Comment: you are on the right track missing a bit though